# Can I add, subtract, multiply and divide multivariable functions with different domains?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

Can I add, subtract, multiply and divide multivariable functions with different domains?

Say if I have $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R^p\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

> For instance:
>
> If $$f(x,y)=x^2+y$$
> and
> $$g(x,y,z)=x^3+y+z$$ is $f(x,y)+g(x,y,z)=x^3+x^2+2y+z$ now a function of 4 variables, $(f+g):\mathbb R^4 \rightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: How would you add a 4-vector to a 2-vector?

Comment: If you write $f(x,y,z):=x^2+y$ you can add $f$ and $g$ in the way you proposed.

Comment: @Randall I clarified the question.